# Creating activities in code adds extraneous contact to 'with' field

Tags: contacts, api, activities, activity

So we create an activity when a contact 'refers a friend', we want it on both users Contact. This is working thus:

```
$activity = civicrm_api(
      'Activity',
      'create',
      array(
          'version' => 3,
          'sequential' => 1,
          'activity_type_id' => 60, //refer activity
          'status_id' => 2,  // complete
          'source_contact_id' => $post['contactId'], 
          'target_contact_id' => $contact['contact_id'], //person who created it
          'activity_subject' =>
             'Referred by a mate: ' . $post['contactId'],
      )
);
```

Works correctly to link the two contacts via the Activity.

But - in the 'With' field, it also adds a second person each time, unrequested. The extra persons contactId increments by 1 each time - which may be a hint.

We've logged all through our code, and through Core trying to find where this is being added, but can't find. Does anyone have any hints on where to look/log for this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm fairly sure this issue was actually a dev environment specific issue. The dev database wasn't using the full 'activity' table (as it was so large) and thus creating some oddities.

If I see it again on a live env I'll have to investigate in future though.